# HTML File upload plugin for CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I need to add a plugin for CKEditor that can insert an html file from my hard drive into the textarea. I looked for CKFinder, but it appears that it cannot upload html files. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the `allowedExtensions` in CKFinder's config.php file, or its equivalent file in ASP. A little lower than halfway the file, just below the warning comment about Flash files, you will find them. See the screenshot how I customized them.

[image: Screenshot config.php]

Comment: in addition to adding it to the config file, you can add allowedextensions inline to your ckeditor instance depending on preference / architecture.